# Automatically filling form fields based on dropdown selection using Rails & Coffee

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, coffeescript

I am very new to Ruby on Rails and Coffeescript and I'm trying to "translate" a simple calculator app that was written in VB many years ago.  The user can select one of several braiders, each of which have 3 unchangeable parameters.  The selected braider's values, along with other values filled in by the user, are then run through several equations to return results to the user.  The result is correct, but I would like to be able to have the user see the three values for the selected machine before actually running the calculation.  I would like to have them as form fields for consistency on the interface, but if there's another way of doing it that I'm missing, I'm open to ideas.

This is the section of the form that I would like to update.  When a braider is selected, I want the number_of_carriers, carrier_speed and capstan_diameter to be automatically filled in.  Each braider object has those values stored in the database.

```
            <%= f.collection_select :braider_id, Braider.all, :id, :name, {prompt: "Select a Braider"}, data: { braiderChange: true } %></br>
            <%= f.label ("Number of Carriers") %> 
            <%= f.text_field :number_of_carriers %> </br> 
            <%= f.label ("Carrier Speed") %> 
            <%= f.text_field :carrier_speed %> </br>
            <%= f.label ("Capstan Diameter") %>
            <%= f.text_field :capstan_diameter %></br>
```

This is the Coffeescript I wrote just to verify that the onchange event was working.  I would like "TEST" to be the relevant values from the database, but I just can't seem to figure out how.

```
$ ->
  $(document).on "change", "[data-braiderChange]", ->
  document.getElementById("braidcalc_number_of_carriers").value = "TEST"
  document.getElementById("braidcalc_carrier_speed").value = "TEST"
  document.getElementById("braidcalc_capstan_diameter").value = "TEST"
  return
return
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: To access database runtime? No you can't access db runtime from web client (browser), but you can use an ajax call which will return the desired output for you to use. Take a look here http://coffeescriptcookbook.com/chapters/jquery/ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue and this rails cast helped me solve it well. Try implementing an adapted version of this http://railscasts.com/episodes/88-dynamic-select-menus

Comment: Thanks!  This definitely put me on the right track.